# CSS optimization post processing using Angular-CLI

Tags: css, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am working on a angular project and the cli does a lot of cool optimizations for production build like minifications, but is there a way to optimize css to use **dynamic shorter codes for css class names**. I have searched a lot but didn't find anything for this specific use case. I found about css-loader but I am not sure on how to use it with angular-cli.

This is what I want the build process to achieve:

[image: eg. Facebook css short codes for class names]

Comment: Were you able to do this? I am trying to do exactly this.

Comment: @AsifulNobel no i was not able to achieve this